# render page after for loop is finished node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm having an async problem, and I've followed a lot of articles online to try and get this issue fixed, but it hasn't done anything.

```
 async function getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList(req, res, rows, allowedToAddMoreClients, alertMessage) {
     
      let sessionData2 = []
      var getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList = "select * from SCHEDULE WHERE CLIENT_USERNAME = ? AND ASSIGNED_TRAINER = ?"
      mysqlconn.connect(async function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
            return;
          }
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
        mysqlconn.query(getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList, [rows[i].USERNAME, req.session.username], async function(err, sessionData) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                for (var x = 0; x < sessionData.length; x++) {
                    sessionData2.push(sessionData[x].SESSION_STATUS)
                    console.log(sessionData2)
                }


            }
           
        })
}


})
await res.render('trainerclientlist.ejs', {data: rows, trainerFirstName: req.session.firstname, trainerLastName: req.session.lastname, allowedToAddMoreClients: allowedToAddMoreClients, profilePhoto: req.session.profilePhoto, alertMessage: req.session.selectedalertmessage, sessionData: sessionData2})
console.log(sessionData2)

}
```

what happens is that `console.log(sessionData2)` happens AFTER the page is rendered, `await res.render('trainerclientlist.ejs', {data: rows, trainerFirstName: req.session.firstname, trainerLastName: req.session.lastname, allowedToAddMoreClients: allowedToAddMoreClients, profilePhoto: req.session.profilePhoto, alertMessage: req.session.selectedalertmessage, sessionData: sessionData2})`. How can i fix this?

Comment: Don't call it there, you would call it after the mysql connection returned the results fully.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK but where would that be in the code?

Comment: Calling query over and over again in a loop is very inefficient, not only that it is what is causing you to go out of sync, you're firing off the loop super-fast synchronously and it doesn't care how long it takes for query to respond back. I would ask if there's a better way to perform your querying and not loop like that, if not you would need to approach this differently with a queue approach and when finished run res.render

Comment: oh okay, good to know, thank you. Basically what I am doing is calling the function `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList()` after a first query is done. then i use the results to do this query. I do it like this becuase there could be up to 25 `rows[i].USERNAME`, so i felt like I needed a loop. However, if you have any other suggestions then, that would be great

Comment: I made a post to maybe help visualize what's happening where it can be fixed. As for your MySQL design/query you can always make it more efficient to avoid these types of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { // I'd avoid this line
// This will force query x-amount of times, 
  mysqlconn.query(getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList, [rows[i].USERNAME, req.session.username], async function(err, sessionData) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // this could had been returned 200ms ->5s from when it's called
      for (var x = 0; x < sessionData.length; x++) {
        sessionData2.push(sessionData[x].SESSION_STATUS)
        console.log(sessionData2)
      }
      // I'd make your res.render call here or call for the next query till all are finished and when none left, now call res.render here...
    }

  })
}
// probably took 1-20ms to complete the loop and so sessionData2 is not ready..
console.log(sessionData);
```

The issue I see is that you run a loop around a query call, that does not wait for each callback, but fires each query and sometime in the future the callback is received. Given this happens all to fast, you can imagine the MySQL server responded back with a delay and it was that exactly that makes sessionData undefined. If you put a setTimeout of 5 seconds it should be defined because enough time was given (but don't do this... bad idea).

The biggest fix you can make is to set this up so you do not have to loop through rows.length... then you can simply run the res.render when MySQL responds back.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I am going to look into fixing it like you mentioned. thanks again

Comment: There's a lot of MySQL experts around here that would be happy to help you sort a more efficient approach.